# How to make a HTML table with the middle column heading having two rows with 1 column on the left and right of it?

Tags: html, html-table

```
<table class="container">

  <thead>

      <th rowspan="2">Device</th>

      <th class="container-costings" colspan="6">NETWORK</th>
      <tr class="costings-headings">
        <td>
          O2 Recycle
        </td>
        <td>
          EE
        </td>
        <td>
          Vodafone
        </td>
        <td>
          Three
        </td>
        <td>
          Mazuma
        </td>
        <td>
          Carphone W
        </td>
      </tr>

      <th rowspan="2">Device</th>



  </thead>
</table>
```

I thought adding

```
<th rowspan="2">Device</th>
```

After the tr which creates the rows in one column would work but unfortunately, it just goes to the next line at the start instead of going to the right hand side of the middle.

The aim is to make it look like the attached image[image]

Unfortunaetelt the last column in green goes to the next line at the moment and i am confused as to why since it is still within thead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (you need to do the CSS formatting)

https://jsfiddle.net/fraggley/2L4qcats/9/

```
<table class="container">

  <thead>

      <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>Device</td>
      <td class="text-center" colspan=6>Network</td>
      <td rowspan=2>Average</td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>o2</td>
      <td>EE</td>
      <td>Vodafone</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Mazuma</td>
      <td>CPW</td>
      </tr>

  </thead>
</table>
```